# Commit Ignored Files in GIT using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I'm trying to Commmit some DLL files to Git using Visual Studio. I have excluded these files *.DLL using the Git ignore file but I'd still expect to be able to Stage and Commit them using the Commit diaglogue. The problem is that they don't appear in the dialogue even when I select the Show Ignored Files option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type the name of ignored files manually, git will add these files and then commit

Answer (score 0):

Are the dlls already in your repository (from a previous commit) ? If so then delete the dlls first in your solution and then commit again (after you ignore file is ok).